# Neovim Clipboard Selection

Tags: neovim, os-clipboard

I am using neovim 0.2.3 dev and xfce4-clipman clipboard manager. I want to copy from the neovim into registers and put it into clipman register. How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got around the problem I posted. I am leaving the solution if and when anyone gets stuck in similar situations.

Put this snippet into your init.nvim. Then install xclip. For easy manipulation you can also use some gui clipboard manager like xfce4-clipman. But xclip is necessary for the following snippet.

```
let g:clipboard = {
  \   'name': 'xclip-xfce4-clipman',
  \   'copy': {
  \      '+': 'xclip -selection clipboard',
  \      '*': 'xclip -selection clipboard',
  \    },
  \   'paste': {
  \      '+': 'xclip -selection clipboard -o',
  \      '*': 'xclip -selection clipboard -o',
  \   },
  \   'cache_enabled': 1,
  \ }
```

Comment: Just adding xclip, without the snippet, was enough for me with neovim 0.8.3 on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Yes, because nvim core has included the config since then.