# How to set copyq to handle clipboard?

Tags: neovim, os-clipboard, linux-debian

I want to let [CopyQ clipboard manager](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) handle clipboard (I am using `set clipboard+=unnamed` setting). To that end, this setting was added to init.vim file:

```
    let g:clipboard = {  
        \ 'name': 'myClipboard',  
        \ 'copy': {  
        \    '+': 'copyq add -',  
        \    '*': 'copyq add -',  
        \ },
        \ 'paste': {
        \    '+': '+',
        \    '*': '*',
        \ },
        \ 'cache_enabled': 1,
        \ }
```

It sort of works, but there are couple of  problems/questions:

1. Every time nvim is started, a `clipboard: error: -1` error is briefly shown on the status line. What's that about?
2. `copyq add -` does add the item to copyq clipboard, but it doesn't select it, i.e. `Ctrl+v` would not paste the item. To also select it, `copyq select 0` command should be ran; can this be combined in `clipboard.copy.{+,*}`?
3. How to set `clipboard.paste.{+,*}` to use copyq?

**Related:**

- [Neovim Clipboard Selection](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15212/36764)

**Edit:** additional info:

```
NVIM v0.4.4
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compilation: /usr/bin/cc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/neovim-eK2ojg/neovim-0.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DDISABLE_LOG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -O2 -DNDEBUG -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fno-common -fdiagnostics-color=always -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -I/build/neovim-eK2ojg/neovim-0.4.4/build/config -I/build/neovim-eK2ojg/neovim-0.4.4/src -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -I/build/neovim-eK2ojg/neovim-0.4.4/build/src/nvim/auto -I/build/neovim-eK2ojg/neovim-0.4.4/build/include
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
```

`:help clipboard` suggests g:clipboard value is to be a string, not an array:

```
:help clipboard
                                 *g:clipboard*
To configure a custom clipboard tool, set g:clipboard to a dictionary.
For example this configuration integrates the tmux clipboard: >

    let g:clipboard = {
          \   'name': 'myClipboard',
          \   'copy': {
          \      '+': 'tmux load-buffer -',
          \      '*': 'tmux load-buffer -',
          \    },
          \   'paste': {
          \      '+': 'tmux save-buffer -',
          \      '*': 'tmux save-buffer -',
          \   },
          \   'cache_enabled': 1,
          \ }
```

Comment: `g:clipboard` expects an array, not a string - see the help for the variable. It's hard to tell without the `:messages`, though

Comment: @Zoe nvim help suggests it should be str, not array. See edits.
`:messages` only displays the same clipboard error as described in `1.`

Comment: ah, I see. 0.6.0-dev says it should be an array - assumed that applied to earlier versions as well.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

A [possible solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15212/neovim-clipboard-selection?rq=1) is to send the clipboard to `xclip` and allow copyq to pick up from there:

```
let g:clipboard = {
  \   'name': 'xclip-xfce4-clipman',
  \   'copy': {
  \      '+': 'xclip -selection clipboard',
  \      '*': 'xclip -selection clipboard',
  \    },
  \   'paste': {
  \      '+': 'xclip -selection clipboard -o',
  \      '*': 'xclip -selection clipboard -o',
  \   },
  \   'cache_enabled': 1,
  \ }
```